# Finding duplicate element in an array?

Tags: java, c++, algorithm

I saw a interview question as follows:

One number in array is duplicating.Find it

Simple solution is as follows:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
{  
    dup = false;
    for(j=0;j<n;j++){
        if(i!=j && a[i]= a[j]){
            dup = true;
        }

       if(dup == true)
          return a[i]
     }
}
```

But I want to implement it in O(n log(n)) and in O(n) time.  How can i do it?

Comment: Are you programming in C++ or Java? If your question is language-agnostic, remove language-specific tags.

Answer (score 6):

Sort the array (that can be done in the first O (n Log n) then the comparison just has to be done for the adjacent elements. Or just put the array into a hash table and stop if you find the first key  with an exsting entry.

Comment: Why would you do that when using a set is (close to) O(n)?

Answer (score 3):

I'm answering to "Finding duplicate element in an array?"

You search for i and j from 0 to < n, and later you check for j != i. Instead you could form your loops like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<n-1; i++) 
{
    for (j=i+1; j<n; j++)
    {
         if (a[i] == a[j])
         {
            return i;
         }
    }
}
return -1;
```

Repeatedly setting dup=false is nonsense. Either dup is still false, or it was true, then you left the code with 'return'.

Answer (score 2):

Writing the previous answers in actual code (Java):

O(n log n) time:

```
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++)
        if (arr[i] == arr[i - 1])
            return arr[i];
    throw new Exception(); // error: no duplicate
```

O(n) time:

```
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (set.contains(arr[i]))
            return arr[i];
        set.add(arr[i]);
    }
    throw new Exception(); // error: no duplicate
```

Comment: Hash Table based data structure might have Worst Case complexity of O(n^2) if there are collisions.

Since Red Black Tree is self balancing tree the worst case complexity of Tree based data structure would be O(nlogn).

Comment: Make that `Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>(arr.length);` (if probability of a duplicate close to the start is low - if it is high, you're better off with a tree implementation of `Set`). Use foreach loop. Just add the element and return if `!Set.add(arr[i])`.

Answer (score 0):

I *recommend* to use the *hash-map* (assuming no collisions) to solve it.

```
 private boolean hasDuplicate(int[] arr) {
        Map<Integer, Boolean> map = new HashMap();
        // find the duplicate element from an array using map
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if(map.containsKey(arr[i])) {
                return true;
            } else {
                map.put(arr[i], true);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Time complexity : O(n)

Space complexity : O(n)

Another approach is sorting and comparing and but the sorting adds *extra overhead*.

Answer (score 0):

By using collections we can go for below code snippet -

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
    for (String arrayElement : arr) {
        if (!set.add(arrayElement)) {
            System.out.println("Duplicate Element is : " + arrayElement);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Find O(n) complexity solution as below -

```
int ar[]={0,1,2,3,0,2,3,1,0,2};
    Set  <Integer>mySet=new HashSet<>();
    for(int n:ar){
        if(!mySet.add(n)){
            System.out.println(" "+n);
        }
    }
```

And another process with lesser space complexity O(N) and possibly O(n Log n) --

```
    public void duplicateElementSolution(int ar[]){
     Arrays.sort(ar);

    for(int i=0;i<(ar.length-1);i++){
        if(ar[i]==ar[i+1]){
            System.out.println(" "+ar[i]);
        }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var containsDuplicate = function(nums) {
    const set = new Set();
    for (const num of nums) {
        if (set.has(num)) {
            return true; // Found a duplicate
        }
        set.add(num);
    }
    return false; // No duplicates found
};
```

Comment: This seems to be JS and not whatever the OP used, and the question is asking about time complexity. Please try to add a little more to your answer to address the question if possible. Also, you're using `var` when you know you have `const`? Why?

Answer (score -1):

Reference `java.util.TreeSet` which is implemented Red-Black tree underlying, it's `O(n*log(n))`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question, and should be a comment instead.

Answer (score -1):

(The question in its current form is a little confusing - my answer is assuming that the question is about finding two numbers in an array that sum to a given value)

Since the given array is unsorted, I am assuming that we are not allowed to sort the array (i.e. the given order of the array cannot be changed).

The simplest solution IMHO is to iterate over each number `x` and check if `I-x` occurs anywhere in the arrays. This is essentially what your O(n^2) solution is doing.

This can be brought down to O(n) or O(nlogn) by making the search faster using some sort of fast set data structure. Basically, as we iterate over the array, we query to see if `I-x` occurs in the set.

Code (in Python):

```
l=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
seen=set()

I=11
for item in l:
        if I-item in seen:
                print "(%d,%d)"%(item,I-item)
        seen.add(item)
```

The complexity of the solution depends on the insert/lookup complexity of the `set` data structure that you use. A hashtable based implementation has a O(1) complexity so it gives you a O(n) algorithm, while a tree based `set` results in a O(nlogn) algorithm.

Edit:

The equivalent data structure to Python's `set` would be `stl::set` in C++ and `TreeSet`/`HashSet` in Java. The line `I-x in seen` would translate to `seen.contains(I-x)` in Java and `seen.find(I-x)==seen.end()` in C++.

Comment: am not understanding it, am not much familiar with python.U are just adding item to set, how can we find if sum = i in this codE?

Comment: @mindtree: As I said in the explanation preceding the code, if a+b=X we have b=X-a. So we just check if X-a is in the set of previously encountered numbers (using the expression `I=item in seen`).

Comment: The question has been edited, moving away from this assumption, so it might be better if you delete this answer.